# Criar Json com uma grande quantidade de Dados e Retornar com WebApi

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

Cenário: 
Tenho um WebApi que executa um método na minha camada de serviço que executa uma query quer retorna 500k linhas de resultado, contendo 90 colunas.

**Método que faz a consulta e percorre os resultados:**

```
   using (var command = Session.Connection.CreateCommand())
   {
      command.CommandText = dataSource.Query;

      var name = "";

      using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
      {
         while (reader.Read())
         {

         }
      }
   }
```

Hoje para tentar construir um JSON eu utilizo a classe JsonTextWriter:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(int.MaxValue);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);

using (JsonWriter jrWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
{
   using (var command = Session.Connection.CreateCommand())
   {
      command.CommandText = dataSource.Query;

      var name = "";

      using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
      {
         while (reader.Read())
         {
            int fields = reader.FieldCount;

            jrWriter.WriteStartObject();

            for (int i = 0; i < fields; i++)
            {
               jrWriter.WritePropertyName(name);

               name = reader.GetName(i);

               if (reader[i] == null)
               {
                  jrWriter.WriteValue("");
               }
               else if (reader[i] is string)
               {
                  jrWriter.WriteValue(reader[i].ToString().Trim());
               }
               else if (reader[i] is bool)
               {
                  var value = (bool)reader[i];

                  if (value)

                     jrWriter.WriteValue("true");

                  else
                  {

                     jrWriter.WriteValue("false");

                  }
                  else if (reader[i] is DateTime)
                  {
                     jrWriter.WriteValue(DateTime.Parse(reader[i].ToString()));
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    jrWriter.WriteValue(reader[i].ToString().Trim().Replace(",", "."));
                  }

                  jrWriter.WriteEndObject();
             }
       }
  }
```

}

**Problema:**

Após iterar 150k registros , é gerado o erro SystemOutMemoryException

Já tentei diversas outras soluções para tentar enviar essa massa de dados para front, mas sempre esbarro na mesma exception.

Já tentei converter cada registro meu para um array de bytes e incluir cada registro em um Array de array de bytes, dessa forma até consegui iterar todos os registros, mas na hora de fazer o retorno para o front, estoura a exception SystemOutMemoryExeption.

Se alguém já precisou enviar grande quantidade de dados pela webApi, estou aberto a receber dicas de melhor forma para fazer isso, pois acredito que o problema esta em sempre ter que converter tudo pra string.

Comment: Não só em C#, mas em várias outras linguagens, o `array` anterior à geração de dados ocupa muito espaço na memória. Não há um jeito de particionar essa execução?

Comment: Você já pensou como vai ficar a performance da pagina que vai exibir essa informação? Acho que você deveria pensar na possibilidade de paginar isso.

Comment: Infelizmente, não tem como eu paginar isso, vou exibir essas informações em um componente de PIVOT para analise de dados, ou seja deve estar disponivel toda a massa de dados.

Comment: Toda letra nesse Json seu ocupa um espaço de memoria para existir e também precisa ser processada... Você vai precisar de maquina para rodar isso, não tem milagre em uma situação dessas.  Por mais otimizado que seu código seja, para ser realmente rápido vai precisar de servidor

Comment: Além do estouro de memória, esta operação vai levar muito tempo até gerar o resultado para seus usuários.

Imagino que esteja usando Sql Server, correto? Um melhor caminho seria criar SSIS packages para exportar seu arquivo, e uma vez concluído, retornar o path para o arquivo. Ou seja, gerar o seu arquivo de maneira assíncrona.

Comment: Acho que a melhor forma de trafegar muitos dados é utilizando query paginada. https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/ASP-NET-Site-Videos/paging-and-querying

Comment: @DiegoSilvaLima Se você realmente quer fazer dessa forma, tente gerar o JSON em arquivo e não em memória e no final faça o stream do arquivo como retorno.

Comment: Eu também passei por esse problema, mas foi ao gerar o json em delphi, não é problema do C# e sim do array. O que fiz para evitar esse erro foi particionar a informação

Answer (score 1):

@DiegoSilvaLima

Eu vejo quatro possiveis soluções.

1) Particione a busca das informações, ou seja, ao invés de pegar as 500k linhas de uma vez, dispare requests asyncs encadeados que vão buscar 50K por vez (por exemplo) e vai montando seu PIVOT e liberando memória enquanto faz isso.

2) Vai precisar de muito mais memória ram e não tem outra maneira. Você está guardando TUDO na ram e 500k linhas dependendo do tamanho dessas linhas não tme muito o que fazer.

3) Faça um mix entre memória ram e arquivo. Vá processando tudo, guardando aos poucos em arquivo (ou um BD) para salvar o JSON final e depois você vai lendo desse arquivo o JSON e novamente montando o PIVOT conforme vai lendo e liberando memória.

4) **RECOMENDADO** Paginação. O PIVOT é totalmente capaz de exibir informações páginadas. E depois pense no seu usuário final. Que usuário humano de um sistema consegue ver (ou sequer tem interesse em ver) 500k de linhas de uma tabela de uma única vez? Você vai fazer ele esperar muito mais pelo resultado, a página vai travar (tenho quase certeza que o chrome vai querer matar a aba por não estar respondendo a muito tempo).

Eu não consigo imaginar nenhum cenário onde não possa ter páginação para um volume tão grande de informações.

Caso realmente não possa paginar, sei la porque, eu acho que a única solução para você é o item 2. Mais memória ram, muito mais.

Caso você esteja lidando com análise de dados, dai entra em outro aspecto que não involve própriamente melhoria no código C# nem nada disso.
Envolve pré-computar os dados, transformando eles em outras estruturas menores e já computadas/análisadas. Mas mesmo assim isso não vai isentar a necessidade de mais memória.

E lembre, se esse seu sistema for multi-usuário o que poderia acontecer se 3 usuários solicitarem esse mesmo relatório ao mesmo tempo no mesmo servidor.